# Can you get more performance using multiple websockets on one Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, performance, websocket

Ok guys, is it useful to generate more than one websocket instance on a Node.js server? I mean possibly you also create subworkers..

I know, it depends on your hardware and the network cards maximum. But can you reach this maximium with only one task or can you get more performance with several parallel processes?

Comment: What do you mean by "more performance"?  What exact measure do you care about?  In most cases, you can improve the ability for a server to handle high load if you use sticky clustering up to one process per actual CPU in the server.  Depending upon specifics of your situation, you may run into other bottlenecks too that need to be addressed such as network bandwidth, total number of simultaneous connections, etc...

Comment: I mean the maximal number of active connections compared to cpu usage. The main question was what benefit can i gain, if i bind serveral  websockets to serveral http ports or what kind of system could benefits from that.

Comment: If you're asking about maximizing the number of connected sockets, then put that in your question.  That particular subject has been discussed in many other articles and the things you need to do is highly dependent upon what OS you are running too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the CPU count in your server. Parallel processes (the `cluster` module) aren't a silver bullet for performance - on a 1 CPU system they might even decrease it just due to overhead. But if you have more than one CPU, a NodeJS process CANNOT use that extra horsepower. The `cluster` module solves this. Used properly you can use all the available CPU power on the system.

Note that this has nothing to do with WebSockets themselves. This is a core NodeJS architectural constraint. But WebSockets are a great use-case where clustering is advantageous...